# Why git track all my new files on my Desktop?

Tags: git, repository

I have a "problem", when I create (or download) any folder/file on my Desktop, Git that track? 
Why is that?

Is that normal or not?

```
O.S. Windows 10

Git version: latest at this moment
```

Well,  when I open my VS code, code suggest to me to commit changes. That makes my problem because I have thousands of files that git tracks.

Comment: Do you have a `.git` in the root folder?

Comment: Hmmm, yes I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you created the repo on desktop or the C drive which contains desktop folder

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop
```

by

```
git init
```

Please check its status by

```
git status
```

So check for `.git` file in any of the folders which contains the desktop folder and delete it.

To view hidden files in Windows please refer [Show hidden files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files)

Comment: How can I, when is .git hidden?

Comment: Please refer [Show hidden files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files)

Answer (score 1):

You have created a git repo form your Desktop.

In order to cancel it delete the `.git` folder and then create a new folder for your code and execute:

```sh
# Change to the required directory (or use windows explorer)
cd <folder name>
```

If you are using git bash you can right-click on the folder and execute git-bash to get the CLI command line (terminal)

[image]

```sh
# init the git repository in the desired folder
git init
```

If you are working on an actual project go to https://gitignore.io and grab your `.gitignore`. Copy the content and place it inside `.gitignore` file in your new created folder